# Adding TextBoxes to a list in another class

Tags: c#, list, textbox

I created three text boxes calls **HighOffSetX**, **HighOffSetY**, and **HigOffSetZ**.
I want to add them to a list called **HighOffSets**.  The problem that I am running into is how to add the text boxes into a list in another class.

When I try to add **HighOffSetX** to my list I get an error that **HighOffSetX** is not recognized. What do I do so my class recognizes the text boxes?  I do not have a lot of experience in GUIs with C#.  I looked on Google and stack and could not find an answer that helped me out.  Here is the code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace UCAGui
{
  public class CaliberationGUI: Form
  {
    List<TextBox> HighOffSets = new List<TextBox>();

    public CaliberationGUI()
    {
        HighOffSets.Add(this.HighOffSetX); //This line gives me an error

    }
  }
}
```

I changed the names of the text boxes to **HighOffSetX**, **HighOffSetY**, and **HigOffSetZ**.  Here is the generated code from ConfigForm.Designer.cs

```
        this.HighOffSetX.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(60, 28);
        this.HighOffSetX.Name = "HighOffSetX";
        this.HighOffSetX.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
        this.HighOffSetX.TabIndex = 5;
```

If you want me to post the generated code C# created when I added the text boxes let me know.

Comment: You need to have a TextBox with a `Name` of `HighOffsetX`. You can change this in the form designer by changing the `Name` field. I believe this field defaults to `TextBox1` or something along those lines

Comment: debug your code... what you have should work.

Comment: @MaxOvrdr I thought I couldn't debug my code until I get rid of all the errors in the Error List

Comment: @drew_w.  The text boxes are name HighOffSetX, HighOffSetY, and HigOffSetZ.  I added the code for HighOffSetX above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared your textbox in a different form.You can't access that textbox without an instance of `ConfigForm`.Create a new instance of your second Form, or pass it via the constructor:

```
public class CaliberationGUI: Form
{
    private ConfigForm configForm;
    List<TextBox> HighOffSets = new List<TextBox>();
    public CaliberationGUI(ConfigForm config)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.configForm = config;
        HighOffSets.Add(this.configForm.HighOffSetX);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I am getting an inaccessible due to protection level. I can solve in by changing HighOffSetX to public.  Is that recommended in C# or is there a better way to do that?

Comment: well, if you want to access it from a different form then you have to make it public